# Jquery events working only in document ready

Tags: jquery, events, document, ready

i start a little web-project with .net MVC 3. My Problem: 
i included Jquery 1.8.3.js. But my functions doesnt work in the javascript files:

This isn´t working:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:button').button();
});

$('#testbut').on('click', function (event, ui) {

    alert("CLICK");

});
```

this is still working fine:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('input:button').button();

    $('#testbut').on('click', function (event, ui) {

    alert("CLICK");

    });
});
```

i have no idea why.

the include is in right order.

Comment: Why not use the one that is working? It's working because you must wait for the element to exist before you try to select it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The first example fails because the code is being executed as the page is being loaded and the elements it refers to haven't been loaded yet. This is also why the second example does work.

By placing your code in a document ready block it holds off executing it until the page has loaded.

Answer (score 1):

When you put blocks of code in `$(document).ready()`, it waits to attach listeners to the targets after the document has been loaded. So in your first example, jquery attaches the listener `$('#testbut').on('click', function (event, ui) {` but the DOM has not loaded the element yet. In the second example, it attaches the listener only after document is loaded.